# Java методы, сокращенные до выражений

Tags: java, c#, синтаксис

В C#, начиная с версии 6.0, метод, который только возвращает значение:

```
public int func(int x)
{
    return x*x;
}
```

Можно сократить до выражения ([expression-bodied member](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members)):

```
public int func(int x) => x*x;
```

Существуют ли подобные сокращения в Java?

Comment: @RomanDanilov, лямбда - это функция, а здесь просто сокращенный синтаксис. Это не лямбда.

Comment: @Андрей, согласен

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Нет, объявления членов класса с помощью выражения в Java нет.

В последней спецификации Java 9 [в синтаксисе объявления метода](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4) явно указано тело:

```
MethodDeclaration:
    {MethodModifier} MethodHeader MethodBody
```

И предложения такого для Java я не нашел.

Можете посмотреть в сторону языка Kotlin, он работает под JVM и предоставляет много синтаксического сахара, в том числе [объявление функции](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-syntax.html#defining-functions):

```
fun sum(a: Int, b: Int) = a + b
```